# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar el email del usuario registrado?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Estoy atascado en esta parte, necesito mostrar el email del usario que accedió,  pero no me enseña nada una vez que esta dentro de la aplicación.

```
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
TextView MostrarCorreo;

@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.nav_header_main);

    firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }

    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    MostrarCorreo = findViewById(R.id.MostrarCorreo);

    MostrarCorreo.setText("Hola"+user.getEmail());
}
```

También lo intento de esta manera y no sucede nada:

```
 FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    if (user != null) {

        String email = user.getEmail();

        mostrar.setText(email);
    }
```

Comment: Estas seguro de que estas obteniendo el email en la variable `email`.

Comment: Estoy usandolo a como indican los desarrolladores de firebase

Answer (score 0):

Una vez que acceda el usuario utiliza la siguiente función para detectar

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var name, email, photoUrl, uid, emailVerified;
if (user != null) {
name = user.displayName;
email = user.email;
photoUrl = user.photoURL;
emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
uid = user.uid;  
mostrar.setText(email);
}
```